# The multiple regression model - The minimum sum of squares

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics

I am struggeling with this definition the minimum sum of squares for a Matrix $M$:

The minimum value of $f(β)$ where $β = (X′X)^{−1}X′y$ from the system of normal equations $X′Xβ = X′y$ is $$y′(I − X(X′X)^{−1}X′)y = y′My$$,
with $M = (I − X(X′X)^{−1}X′)$ a symmetric, idempotent (T × T)-Matrix. 
The trace of $M$ is
$\operatorname{tr(M)} = \operatorname{tr}(I)−\operatorname{tr}(X(X′X)^{−1}X′) = T −K $and is 
equal to the rank $r(M)$.

What is meant by the rank $M$(can this be the "real" rank of the Matrix $M$) and how to come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace of an idempotent matrix is always equal to it's rank.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) The rank of a matrix is the size of the largest linear independent basis of the matrix.

[Idempotent Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix)

Comment: so the rank is M and how to come to this conclusion?

Comment: M = (I − X(X′X)^{−1}X′)

Comment: The `rank' of M is a scalar. Intuitively it is the size of the basis of independent vectors used to describe M. You come to this conclusion by realizing that M = M dot M.

Comment: I thought that the rank of this matrix has two solutions. If $T=K$ then the $tr(M)=0$ otherwise the $rank(M)=N$...